# What is the purpose of RC components to ground in this class AB amplifier?

Tags: capacitor, amplifier

I'm talking about R6/C4. It seems like it would be filtering of some kind as the C4 will have it's voltage at the highest for DC or low frequency input, but I don't really understand the purpose.

[image: schematic]

Comment: What’s the reason for using a PNP that is reverse biased?

Comment: Check your Schematic .The All NPN output stage will go bang ,Should it be NPN/PNP.

Comment: Ignoring above mentioned potential circuit errors, a resistor/capacitor in that configuration will result in negative feedback.  i.e. the transistor will become more linear, but the overall gain will decrease.  The capacitor gives it a frequency component..  https://www.electronics-tutorials.ws/amplifier/emitter-resistance.html   About 1/3 down the page....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *What is the purpose of RC components to ground in this class AB
> amplifier?*

[image]

Q1 is a common-emitter stage that supplies all the voltage gain in the circuit. Normally, for a common-emitter stage, its voltage gain would be R7/R6 but, with the capacitor added across R6, the voltage gain (and distortion) will be increased due to the reactance of the capacitor being small in the mid-band of frequencies.

---

<sub>**Note for Kyle B:** it doesn't result in negative feedback when you add the capacitor - it results in a localized **reduction** of negative feedback around the Q1 stage. Neither does it improve linearity - it actually reduces linearity and creates more signal distortion.</sub>